# my Accordion list expanded all items at same time (react native elements)

Tags: list, react-native, element, accordion

I use react-native-elements library.
in **ListItem Accordion** there is onPress option to expand and unexpand list items.
but when I press one item, all of items expand!
[screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyjEI.png)

[image: screen shot 2]

here is part of my code:

```
export class MyList extends Component {

  state= {
    expanded:false,
  };  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded:false
    };
  }
  handleToggle=()=>{
    const {expanded}=this.state;
    if(expanded){
      this.setState({expanded:false});
    }else{
      this.setState({expanded:true})
    }
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      ...
        <View>
        {list.map((l, i) => (
        <ListItem.Accordion key={i}
  content={
    <>
      <ListItem.Content>
      <ListItem.Title>{l.name}</ListItem.Title>
        <Avatar title={l.name[0]} source={{ uri: l.avatar_url }} />
      </ListItem.Content>
    </>
  }
  isExpanded={this.state.expanded}
  onPress={this.handleToggle}
  
>
  
    <ListItem  key={i} bottomDivider>
      
      <ListItem.Content>
        
        <ListItem.Subtitle>{l.city}</ListItem.Subtitle>
        <View style={styles.subtitleView}>
          <Image source={require('../Images/4.5_stars.svg.png')} style={styles.ratingImage}/>
          <Text style={styles.ratingText}>5 votes</Text>
        </View>
      </ListItem.Content>
      <ListItem.Chevron />
    </ListItem>
  
</ListItem.Accordion>
))}
 ...
```

is it my props problem?? if yes, how can I pass the item for each "onPress"??

Answer (score 0):

Surely you already solved your problem.
I had the same problem and I solved it myself since I couldn't find a solution.
It turns out that it was very simple and probably arises from not being used to the React way of working.

A component must be created for your custom <ListItem.Accordion>,
then you get something like

```
 {Turneras ? (Turneras.map((Turnera, i) => (
                <ItemAccordion Turnera={Turnera} ></ItemAccordion>
            ))) : null
            }
```

As easy as that, since each component will have its state expanded and it works perfectly.